# DIV: full height + scroll

Tags: html, css

I want to have a DIV with:

1. The height = all availbale size
2. Vertical scroll for my content

I can do 1) or 2), but both requirements doesn't work correctly for me.

He is my HTML:

```
<div class="FixedHeightContainer">
  <div class="Content">
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
.FixedHeightContainer
{   
    height: 100%;   
    padding:3px; 
    background:#f00;
}
.Content
{
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#fff;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/demas/9jLayt3v/

In this version the Content is bigger then available height (look at red border at the bottom).

I can set height = 300px and in this case I will have the correctly working scroll, but the height of the Content will be the same for all screen sizes.

How can I make the Content.Height = all avaliable size and Scroll for it content?

Or by other words: i need to have red border equal the browser size and scroll inside the red border

Comment: I didn't get you.. seems like the height is stretching as needed.

Comment: Use this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9jLayt3v/3/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dont forget the viewport.

In your example, I just added the following line:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Thanks. What is viewport? It is parent container? Or it is all parent containers?

Comment: The viewport, in this case, is the web browser thats running your page. In general terms, its the main container "element" @demas

Comment: I have created another div (class="one") https://jsfiddle.net/demas/9jLayt3v/ and it stops working.  So I want to find solution in more general case.

Comment: Looks like I need to set the height for ALL parent tags: html, body, div.one, div.two { height: 100%; }

Comment: I couldn't see your new example @demas. maybe its a outdated url

Comment: It will always take the parent element height (or width) as reference when you use %, so yes, theymust have the height 100% property. 

In some cases you will have to set "position: relative" as well, so the child elements will use it as reference @demas

Answer (score 3):

```css
body{
      overflow: hidden;
}
.FixedHeightContainer
{   
    height: 100vh;   
    padding:3px; 
    background:#f00;
      overflow: auto;
}
.Content
{
  height: 100%;
   overflow:auto;
    background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="FixedHeightContainer">

  <div class="Content">
   blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...    blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...   blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...   blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...   blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...   blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...   blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
  </div>
</div>
```

Try This

Answer (score 0):

Is "all available size" the height of the window? If you don't have to support IE8 you can try 100vh. it takes the percentage of the window height and applies it to the element.
If you have to support IE8 you can use JS to find the height of the element.

Comment: No.   I have other div's with fixed height above and below the FixedHeightContainer.  So all available height = height of the windows - sum(other div's with fixed size)